# Serializing form data doesn't work in asp.net mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

In my html  I have

```
<h2>Title goes here</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myFormID" })) {
        <input type="text" id="testinput" name="testinput" />
        <input type="text" id="testinput2" name="testinput2" />

        <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="submitForm();" />
    }
```

in my js I have

```
function submitForm() { 

    dataString = $("#myFormID").serialize();

    alert(dataString);

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/Controller/Action",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {

            alert('success!');
        },

        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + "<br />" + textStatus + "<br />" + errorThrown);

        }

    }); 

}
```

In my controller file I have:

```
    public ActionResult Action()
    {
        return View();
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Action(string testinput, string testinput2)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

When clicked on "click me" button, I get the following error:
"parsererror
Invalid JSON: "

What am I doing wrong? I am simply trying to pass form data to jquery .ajax.

The alert statement outpust "testinput=gdfgf&testinput2=gfgfd" which is the correct values I entered. SO the error seems to be when serializing....
I am using MVC 3 with razor...I had the impression that passing data between model/view and javascript code was made easier.

Comment: looks like asp.net mvc is expecting JSON Data, but you send data serialized as query string (a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am almost positive that has nothing to do with the data you pass to the `$.ajax` call and everything with the data returned by `/Controller/Action`. Open up Fiddler and examine the response. it is likely malformed (or not JSON at all).

Comment: What should contoller/action return? I will add my controller code.

Comment: @sarsnake I don't know what data you expecting it to return, but it must be a valid JSON, since when you init your AJAX request you set `dataType: "json"`, which means you expect that returned data is JSON. If you don't really care about returned data, then don't set the `dataType`.

Comment: I removed the datatype from ajax call and it worked. thank you.

Comment: however, no article actually addresses the case when I do need to return json from the action. Would I have to manually jsonify the data then?

Comment: @sarsnake Simply return a JSON object like this: `return Json(new {foo:"bar"});`, instead of `return View()`

Answer (score 0):

if your method accepts only int id as parameter, then dataString should be declared as

```
var dataString = { id: $("#myFormID").val() };
```

if you need to pass id and testinput as parameters, then use

```
var dataString = { id: $("#myFormID").val(), testinput: $("#testinput").val() };
```

The parameters and names in dataString mutch match the parameters of your action method.

Comment: I see your point....but I was under the impression that serialization was built into MVC 3 and that's why all I need to do is use this:  dataString = $("#myFormID").serialize();

Comment: `myFormID` is the ID of the form. It doesn't have `val()`. Nor does his `Action` have an `id` parameter. Not sure what are you trying to achieve by this code.